# Run type as process in c#

Tags: c#, command-line, process

I can join videos in windows at command line with

```
type vid1.avi vid2.avi > vidjoined.avi
```

I try to run this in c#:

```
ProcessStartInfo cmdStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
cmdStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmdStartInfo.Arguments = "type vid1.avi vid2.avi > vidjoined.avi";
Process cmdProcess = new Process();
cmdProcess.StartInfo = cmdStartInfo;
cmdProcess.Start();
cmdProcess.WaitForExit(120000);
```

What is wrong with my code?
It runs forever and I get no console output.

Comment: You did not write your code in a class/method.

Comment: does is throw an error or what? Try to see the output with `cmdProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it's valid to concatenate two AVI files together, but that aside:

Try changing your arguments to:

```
cmdStartInfo.Arguments = "/c type vid1.avi vid2.avi > vidjoined.avi"
```

The "/c" will cause the command shell to execute and then exit. 
Also, the working directory is going to be wherever cmd.exe is.  Your relative paths to your files will likely not resolve properly. Either set cmdStartInfo.WorkingDirectory to the directory that your files are in, or use fully qualified paths in your arguments.

Comment: I use mpg indeed and when running it on command line it works. `/c` doesn't help